Help in defining a simple custom fold expr
I am trying to understand the mechanism of foldings, but I am but puzzled on why the following snippet won't work:
vim9script

&l:foldcolumn = 2
if &l:foldmethod != 'diff'
  &l:foldmethod = 'expr'
endif

def MyFoldExpr(): string
  # Check if the current line contains 'def' or 'class'
  if getline(v:lnum) =~ '^\s*\(def\|class\)'
    return '>1'
  # Check if the next line contains 'def' or 'class' to close the fold
  elseif getline(v:lnum + 1) =~ '^\s*\(def\|class\)'
    return '<1'
  else
    return '='
  endif
enddef

&l:foldexpr = MyFoldExpr()

The fold is based on every line starting with a possible number of spaces followed  def or class and it ends in the previous line where the next occurrence of the same regex occurs.
EDIT: FYI I added the above snippet in ./after/ftplugin/python.vim

The problem is your last line:
&l:foldexpr = MyFoldExpr()

This is setting your fold expression to 0, because you're calling the function and assigning its return value to the option.
Try this:
&l:foldexpr = 'MyFoldExpr()'

